# How To: Copy AD Description to Title field

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to populate the `Title` field (in Active Directory) with the current value of the `Description` field.

The following PowerShell command runs **without** producing an error message. However, it does **not** update the `Title` field. (The `title` field remains unchanged.)

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Phoenix Users,DC=domain,DC=local" -Filter * -Properties Description, Title | 
    where { $_.Description -ne $null } | Set-ADUser -Title $_.Description
```

**Side Note:**
The `description` field contains spaces; and the `title` field is currently `<not set>`.

Thoughts?

Comment: AFAIK You will have to use a loop and treat every single user separately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the argument to `-Title` in a scriptblock - this will make PowerShell bind the value of the current pipeline item to `$_`:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Phoenix Users,DC=domain,DC=local" -Filter * -Properties Description, Title | 
    where { $_.Description -ne $null } | Set-ADUser -Title { $_.Description }
```